# using JTable as JScrollPane's columnHeader while maintaining width of each column

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane, jtableheader

just looking for a quick answer: is it possible to use a JTable as a JScrollPane's columnHeader?

I have a configed JTable with different column width and column title, and plan to use the header as the columnHeader of a scrollpane. How can I achieve this? I set the table with

```
scrollPane.setColumnHeaderView(table);
```

but it doesn't show up.

so thanks to Guillaume Polet, it should be

```
scrollpane.setColumnHeaderView(table.getTableHeader());
```

but all the columns have the same width now although I set them with different values in my table. How could I let the table columns show different width?

Comment: I think you should edit your post. I don't know what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I'm simply trying to set the "ColumnHeader" of a JScrollPane with a JTable that contains 0 Rows and only the Header.

Comment: A JLabel can be set as ColumnHeader but I don't understand why a JTable can't.

Comment: Please show us the code. I've modified an example from http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/JScrollPanewithrowandcolumnheaders.htm and JTable as columnHeader works fine (however there are problems with component sizes)

Comment: @boreas as (@Robin) mentioned post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Does it works with a JTable that got at least 1 Row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want the column headers of your table to appear in the column headers of the viewport but you want something else in the viewport view?

Then you need to grab the table header and set it as the column header of the viewport.

Here is an example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestTableHeader {

    protected void initUI() {
        Vector<Vector<Object>> data = new Vector<Vector<Object>>();
        Vector<String> colNames = new Vector<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            colNames.add("Col-" + (i + 1));
        }

        table = new JTable(data, colNames);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        scrollpane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollpane.setColumnHeaderView(table.getTableHeader());
        scrollpane.setViewportView(new JLabel("some label in the viewport view"));
        frame.add(scrollpane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JTable table;
    private JScrollPane scrollpane;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException,
            UnsupportedLookAndFeelException {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TestTableHeader().initUI();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you Guillaume Polet! This almost works, just one problem: I have special requirement on each column's width, they are different and I have set it in my table. but when I use scrollpane.setColumnHeaderView(table.getTableHeader()); all the columns would have the same width. any idea how to avoid this?

Comment: I just tried with a JTableHeader, not working either, still all the columns have the same width.

Comment: @boreas You can access the TableColumModel and set the column pref/min/max width of the underlying columns.

Comment: thank you again! now it should be the last question: I can have to use setMinWidth and setMaxWidth to get the column shown at my specified width, but in that case i can't modify the table width any more in the application. But I need to. The width of each columns are the time duration of each element in the graph below (in the view port of the scrollPane), and I need to be able to modify them when the time duration is not right. so how can I modify the widths?

Comment: done. set the min/max after set the TableHeader to the ColumnHeader of the scrollPane.

Comment: @boreas you don't need a table to instantiate a header (actually it might get into the way later on, as the header keeps a reference to that table) Instead of looping to create the column names for a foo TableModel, loop to create TableColumns and add them to a TableColumnModel.

Comment: @kleopatra Yeah I thought of that too, but I was wondering if he was actually using the table content somewhere else, in which case, it was acceptable to create a whole JTable